# How to assign ng-model a value based on a condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs

OK, I am trying to create a web link directive. The link needs a URL and a text value. In the event the text value does not have a value - the text value will equal the url. For example:

```
<a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a>
```

example when a link has a text value

```
<a href="http://google.com">Search engine</a>
```

in the code below are two input tags that records the url value and the text value. In the event that the text value is blank the text value will equal the url value. Here is the code to my directive:

```
Website1.directive('inputlink', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            urlvalue: '=',
            textvalue: '='
        },
        template:   '<div>' +
                        '<input type="text" ng-model="urlvalue" value="{{urlvalue}}" placeholder="Enter link URL"></input>'+
                        '<input type="text" ng-model="textvalue" value="{{textvalue}}" placeholder="Enter text"></input>' +
                    '</div>'
    }
});
```

So if the textvalue is blank it will equal the urlvalue otherwise the textvalue will have its own value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to change it in a function. like so

```
link: function( $scope, $element, $attributes ) {
    if(!$scope.textvalue) {
       $scope.textvalue = $scope.urlvalue;
    }
}
```

And depending on your requirements you may need to `$watch` it also.